# UDP Hole punching guidance

Tags: networking, firewall, nat, udp

I am trying to experiment with UDP hole punching to try to connect 2 computers. The 2 computers I am trying to connect are on 2 different Wifi created by the same router. Let me call these computers C1 and C2. So I want to create a connection between C1 and C2.
I have 2 public server IPs available where I run a UDP listener server. These servers are S1 and S2.

Experiment 1:

1. Send a UDP packet from C1 to S1 and print the IP and port of the incoming packet. I get IP_C1 and PORT_C1.
2. Send a message back to C1 from S1 using IP_C1 and PORT_C1. This works fine as expected and it remains connected. So in a way I have already punched a hole for S1 to communicate directly with C1.

Experiment 2:

1. Send a UDP packet from C1 to S1 and get IP_C1 and PORT_C1.
2. Send a UDP packet from C2 to S1 and get IP_C2 and PORT_C2.
3. Use S1 to send a message back to C1 using IP_C1 and PORT_C1. This works as before.
4. Use S1 to send a message back to C2 using IP_C2 and PORT_C2. This also works fine.

So now both C1 and C2 are accessible from S1. 
NOTE: What I see is that IP_C1 and IP_C2 are the same so lets call them IP_C. Ports however are different.

Continuing this I tried sending a message from C1 to C2 using IP_C and PORT_C2 as the destination. C2 did not receive the message as expected
I then send a message from C2 to C1 using IP_C and PORT_C1. 
This is where I start getting stuck:
I expected that now the message of C2 will reach C1 since C1 already punched a hole in the NAT going to C2. But C1 does not receive the message.
Continuing if I now send another message from C1 and C2. C2 does not get it.
But even now if I send a message from S1 to C1 or C2 it works.

Experiment 3:

To check whether the IP and port are maintained when the client sends another UDP packet I did the following:

1. Send a UDP packet from C1 to S1 and get IP_C1 and PORT_C1.
2. Send a UDP packet from C2 to S1 and get IP_C2 and PORT_C2.
3. Send a UDP packet from C1 to S2 and get IP_C1_S2 and PORT_C1_S2.
4. Send a UDP packet from C2 to S2 and get IP_C2_S2 and PORT_C2_S2.

Like S1, S2 also easily connects and I see IP_C1=IP_C1_S2=IP_C2=IP_C2_S2=IP_C and PORT_C1=PORT_C1_S1 and PORT_C2=PORT_C2_S2.

So the ports are maintained.

Even with this scenario I am not able to establish communication between C1 and C2. 
So I am not sure why the communication does not work between C1 and C2. How can make that work?

Thanks

Comment: As it stands, this question is too broad because it's currently "If anyone can help guide me as to what other experiments I can do..." Can you [edit](https://serverfault.com/posts/987078/edit) the question to limit the scope? You may also want to delete "experiments" that are not directly relevant to this more limited question.

Comment: I want the communication between C1 and C2 to work. All 3 experiments seemed relevant here because each provided some information and check to help me understand/debug the problem.